# About Flutter/Dart Polymorphism

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, polymorphism

I learned that Dart supports polymorphism,

https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system

However, I encountered following problem.

First, I created Location class and extended Location class by ContentLocation class.

Second, I tried to add ContentLocation class into List.
But It doesn't work!

Moreover, Location a = ContentLocation(...); also doesn't work.
Is there anyone can explain why it happens?

```
//location.dart
class Location {
  final LatLng latLng;
  const Location(this.latLng);
}

//content_location.dart
class ContentLocation extends Location {
  final int cid;
  final String name;
  const ContentLocation(this.cid, this.name, LatLng latLng) : super(latLng);
}

//Doesn't Work
List<Location> locations = [
    ContentLocation(0, "A", LatLng(35.5735, 129.1896))
];
```

Comment: *"Second, I tried to add ContentLocation class into List. But It doesn't work!"* - yes it works

Comment: Sorry, It was my fault that I include Location.dart, not location.dart.
Thank you for your kind answer!!:)

Comment: sure, your welcome